# How to get the value of the Name of an element inside a JSON object?

Tags: json, getvalue

I have the following object:

```
var list = {
    "to do": {
    key: 99, 
    important: ["example1", "example2"], 
    others: ["example3", "example4"]
    }
};
```

I want to understand how I can extract the value `to do` from `list`.

I want to log the value to a variable: `var x = "to do"`

I tried to locate it, but `to do` does not seem to have an index. `list[0] // undefined`.

Does anyone have a simple solution how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys()` to get the keys of `list`. Since you only have one key use `[0]`
If you have more than one key solution may differ

```js
var list = {
    "to do": {
    key: 99, 
    important: ["example1", "example2"], 
    others: ["example3", "example4"]
    }
};
let x=Object.keys(list)[0];
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, extract data from the list variable followed by your key string.

```
   var list = {
        "to do": {
        key: 99, 
        important: ["example1", "example2"], 
        others: ["example3", "example4"]
        }
    };
    var x=list["to do"];
    console.log(x)
```